# Change color of Selected location(dbid) for viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

I am trying to slice a model in viewer.
After slicing the model location is zoomed(or sliced) into view.
The color of selected location is blue. I want to change it on the basis of certain case/conditions.

"model location" is mapped by dbId.

I did not find any option for this.

Comment: Code sample that illustrates what you are talking about?

Comment: Thanks for quick response, Philippe. I got a workaround.
I used setTeamingColor(dbId, color) for the same, and clearSelction().